# Upload Image Using Ajax and PHP and Return Uploaded Image URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to upload image without refresh but i don't have much knowledge about ajax.
I have php file thy return image url when i submit post with ajax function.

**Javascript**

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 

        $('#photoimg').live('change', function()            { 
                   $("#preview").html('');
            $("#preview").html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
        $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
                    target: '#preview'
                                       }
    }).submit();

        });
    });
```

**PHP**

```
  <?php

       $path = "uploads/";

$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp");
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
        $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
        $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];

        if(strlen($name))
            {
                list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
                if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
                {
                if($size<(1024*1024))
                    {
                        $actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
                        $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
                        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
                            {


                                $imge1="uploads/".$actual_image_name;
                                echo $imge1;

                            }
                        else
                            echo "failed";
                    }
                    else
                    echo "Image file size max 1 MB";                    
                    }
                    else
                    echo "Invalid file format..";   
            }

        else
            echo "Please select image..!";

        exit;
    }
        ?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaximage.php'>
Upload your image <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" />
</form>
<div id='preview'>

</div>
<img src = "" id="thumb_img" />
```

Now result is image url. when image select ajax automatically post sand to php.Php save image and return url and this url show in target div.So now i need this url set as background url. Like image select `target` div background change.

Comment: .live is depricated, please use .on

Answer (score 1):

I would just do something like:

```
$('#myForm').ajaxForm(function(url) { 
   $('#preview').css('background-image', "url(" + url + ")"); 
});
```

Comment: can you implement on my code.please actually i have confused.

Comment: Actually it is an implementation, just send back the correct url(or path) by PHP, and set width and height your #preview div

Comment: oh, the selector not the same ... $("#imageform").ajaxForm(function(url) { 
   $('#preview').css('background-image', "url(" + url + ")"); 
});

Comment: Thanks "pszaba" but this method just work on localhost but on server i got error.(Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.musicjee.com/project/". jquery.js:6657
jQuery.extend.style jquery.js:6657
(anonymous function) jquery.js:6576
jQuery.extend.access jquery.js:862
jQuery.fn.css jquery.js:6574
(anonymous function)
options.success jquery.form.js:188
fire jquery.js:1075
self.fireWith jquery.js:1193
done jquery.js:7538
callback)

Comment: You have to set the correct header e.g.: 
header("Content-type:image/png");
echo $img_data; more: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: What you mean set header.Where i set this header function.I mean this will use for redirection but ajax getting response automatically behave of my knowledge maybe i am not right.please help.

Comment: In PHP before you send your image back. This is not a redirection but you define what you going to send.
 $imge1="uploads/".$actual_image_name;
 header("Content-type:image/png");
 echo $imge1;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40576/discussion-between-zohiab-ahmad-and-pszaba)